# Nested dictionnaires in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

Following answers to question posted here, I'm trying to create a simple nested dictionary in Swift. Here's my code, which doesn't compile with error:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

```
var nestedDict = [String: [String: AnyObject]]()
nestedDict["key1"] = ["subKey11": 1, "subKey12": "string b", "subKey13": true]
print(nestedDict)
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

The value you are assigning to `nestedDict["a"]` is not a `[String: AnyObject]`. It is a `[String: Any]`. That's a typological mismatch. You have to cast it:

```
    var nestedDict = [String: [String: AnyObject]]()
    nestedDict["a"] = ["b": 1, "c": "string b", "d": true] as [String: AnyObject]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's also works with if I declare the dict with "var players = [String: [String: Any]]()" as it happens...

Comment: Yes, and I was going to say as part of my answer that that's what you probably want. No one says AnyObject these days, except in some _very_ specialized circumstances.